# Advantages and Disadvantages of Inheritance in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Can anyone tell me what are the Main Advantages and Disadvantages of Inheritance/multi-level inheritence in php.Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: what is the reason to downvote my answer?

Comment: For your answer or question. ( I haven't downvoted your answer)

Comment: @user3647254 i am not pointing you but someone downvote my answer without giving any reason :( (like what is wrong in my question)

Comment: You haven't answered anything yet, how can someone downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advantages:-**

One of the key benefits of inheritance is to minimize the amount of duplicate code in an application by sharing common  code amongst several subclasses. Where equivalent code exists in two related classes, the hierarchy can usually be  refactored to move the common code up to a mutual superclass. This also tends to result in a better organization of  code and smaller, simpler compilation units.

Inheritance can also make application code more flexible to change because classes that inherit from a common  superclass can be used interchangeably. If the return type of a method is superclass

Reusability -- facility to use public methods of base class without rewriting the same
Extensibility -- extending the base class logic as per business logic of the derived class
Data hiding -- base class can decide to keep some data private so that it cannot be altered by the derived class

Overriding--With inheritance, we will be able to override the methods of the base class so that meaningful  implementation of the base class method can be designed in the derived class.

**Disadvantages:-**

1. One of the main disadvantages of inheritance is the increased  time/effort it takes the program to jump through all the levels of overloaded classes. If a given class has ten levels of  abstraction above it, then it will essentially take ten jumps to run through a function defined in each of those classes
2. Main disadvantage of using inheritance is that the two classes (base and inherited class) get tightly coupled.
   This means one cannot be used independent of each other.
3. Also with time, during maintenance adding new features both base as well as derived classes are required to be  changed. If a method signature is changed then we will be affected in both cases (inheritance & composition)
4. If a method is deleted in the "super class" or aggregate, then we will have to re-factor in case of using that  method.Here things can get a bit complicated in case of inheritance because our programs will still compile, but the  methods of the subclass will no longer be overriding superclass methods. These methods will become independent  methods in their own right.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right site for this type of questions, but okay.

Let's say you have some basic class `Base`, which every other class extends. In base you can define things that all other classes can use, e.g. connection to mysqli, so all classes can use `$this->mysqli` and don't need to have it declared.

I built an ecommerce cms, where I use it this way. I also defined a method called `getLink()` which checks if there's a method `getUrl()` and `getTitle()`. These methods are defined in every child class (at my CMS `Product`, `Category`...). Let's take the `Product` class, there are also the methods `getUrl()` and `getTitle()` but the method `getLink()` is in the `Base` which the `Product` extends. I use the method `getLink()` almost everywhere so if I don't want to write it in every class, I just write it in the `Base` and I can use it.

Another example from my CMS: in the `Base` construct I have a check if input with name `global_update` was submitted. It will check if `$this->table` and `$this->id` was defined and if yes, it will update database with the data. Otherwise I would need to define a handler for every update action. This way I have one global for every class and I write own handlers only for more complex forms.

I hope this is understandable, if not, comment and ask.